# Google +1 button on Google sites

Tags: google-plus, google-sites

I have a google site and I want to add several `«+1»-buttons` on one page.
As I understood, all different buttons must be related to different URL's, so I created one more page with a `«+1»-button`, which can be simply added.
Now I want to have the same button on the main page, how can I achieve this?

I've already browsed many things about it, f.ex., https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/
but I can't add Javascript on Google sites!

That's ridiculous, it has information about how to add it for other sites, but not for their own.

Answer (score -1):

I re-read the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#plusonetag-parameters

The ability to control each button individually is available in platform preview only.

Sorry.

Comment: If I do as you said, it will end up with multiple +1-buttons related to one page. So, f.ex., if I click on one of it, all of the counts will go up. That's not what I need, I want the buttons to be different. Do you understand my problem?..

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you want to have +1s for different portions of your page? Let me edit my answer above.

Comment: Thank you anyway! To be more precise, I have lots of quotes on my page and I wanted them to have «likes»… I can't create an individual page for each of them, that's too hard.